# How to get email notification when process on ubuntu screen stopped?

Tags: vps, ubuntu-12.04, monitoring

I have a application running on `Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS` and I am running an application server like `mailman server` or `faye server` on ubuntu screen.

The problem is, at times the process that is running on screen gets stopped and my application crashes because of that.

Now I want to be notified whenever that 'faye server' or 'mailman server' is stopped that is running on screen.

I am using Digital Ocean and I have already setup postfix server.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor process on Linux machine by uisng monit. which will look for existence of pid. its highly configurable, so that you can make process restart automatically when it is down. And its light weight too. Please find the below link

```
http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples
```

Sandeep